# Interpreting this problem from Dummit and Foote

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, group-homomorphism, semidirect-product

Under fair use, I will quote Exercise 22, Section 5.5 from Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra*. Take note that the topic of the section is semidirect products.

> Let $F$ be a field let $n$ be a positive integer and let $G$ be the group  of upper triangular matrices in $GL_n(F)$ (c.f. Exercise 16, Section 5.5).
>
> **(a)** Prove that $G$ is the semidirect product $U \rtimes D$ where $U$ is the set of upper triangular matrices with $1$'s down the diagonal (cf. Exercise 17, Section 2.1) and $D$ is the set of diagonal matrices in $GL_n(F)$.
>
> **(b)** Let $n=2$. Recall that $U \cong F$ and $D \cong F^\times \times F^ \times$ (cf. Exercise 11 in Section 3.1). Describe the homomorphism from $D$ into $Aut(U)$ explicitly in terms of these isomorphisms (i.e., show how each element of $F^\times \times F^ \times$ acts as an automorphism on $F$.

I have already solved part **(a)**. One shows that $U \unlhd G$ and $D \leq G$ and $U \cap D=\{I\}$ and $UD=G$. This implies that $G \cong U \rtimes _\phi D$, where $\phi:D \to Aut(U)$ by conjugation.

For part **(b)**, however, I am confused on what exactly is being asked for. (I understand why $U \cong F$ and $D \cong F^\times \times F^ \times$). Is it merely asking for an explicit homomorphism $h: F^\times \times F ^ \times \to Aut(F)$ which satisfies $G \cong F \rtimes _h (F^ \times \times F ^\times)$? Or is it asking instead for a homomorphism from $D \to Aut(G)$? In either case, do I need to show that the homomorphism is unique?

Take note that my question is more about "logistics" (trying to decipher instructions) than actual mathematics. However, any help with part **(b)** would be welcome and appreciated.

Comment: When you have a semi-direct product $U\rtimes D$, there is a homomorphism $\phi: D\to \operatorname{Aut}(U)$ given by $\phi(d)(u)=dud^{-1}$ which determine (when taken together with $U$ and $D$) the semi-direct product up to isomorphism. The group $U\rtimes D$, or to make the notation depend on $\phi$ $U\rtimes_\phi D$ can be obtained by [this construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product#Inner_and_outer_semidirect_products). Taking that into account, they probably wanted to ask about that homomorphism $\phi$.